# Dynamic SOQL Where IN Clause

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

Will the Where in Clause work with a list of Objects? In this case the list holds a list of IDs. Or do I need to cast this List of Objects to the ID datatype before my Dynamic SOQL.

```
   List<Object> ListOfIDs;

    String query = 'SELECT id FROM Account Where id in :ListOfIDs';

    Database.Query(query);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static and dynamic SOQL need appropriately typed bindings. For this to work you need the "listOfIds" to be one of:

- List<String>
- List<Id>
- or even: List<Account> (where the Account instances include at least the Id field)